# Timing constraints for external ADC for clock generated by FPGA

Tags: adc, fpga, timing-analysis, efinix

I am using an FPGA to generate a 100 MHz clock to an external 8-bit ADC.
The external ADC is the ADC08100 and the valid sample window is -1.5ns to 4.4ns in regards to the rising edge of the clock.  I am using the efinix trion t8 fpga, with the efinity toolchain.

[image: System block diagram]

I am trying to understand how to specify this sample window to the constraints of the FPGA. Here is what I have at the moment

```
set_input_delay -clock clk_100M -reference_pin [get_ports {clk_100M~CLKOUT~*}] -max 4.4 [get_ports {adc_data[*]}]
set_input_delay -clock clk_100M -reference_pin [get_ports {clk_100M~CLKOUT~*}] -min -1.5 [get_ports {adc_data[*]}]
```

I think that this means exactly the opposite - the data is valid only after 4.4ns at the worst case, and -1.5ns at the best case. How can i specify the sample window?

Comment: It might be useful to generate an offset clock in the PLL.

Comment: the t8 can't shift the phase of the clock, i can only generate an inverted clock,